# Statistical test or simple A/B testing

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, inference

Let's say I have two samples from some population. One sample is the control group, the other is the treatment group. Apart from the treatment, the samples should be, on average, equal. I also have some ***binary*** metric that I want to compare. What is the appropriate statistical test for testing the hypothesis that the average of my metric is greater in the treatment group?

Comment: What is the nature of the metric?  Is it binary (presence/absence), continuous, categorical?  We need more information on the outcome and the design of the experiment.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, will update the question.

Comment: There are dozens of answers to similar questions on this site.  Have you tried searching for  similar questions?  I know I have written answers to questions like this at least a dozen times.

Comment: Fisher's exact test, chi-squared test, proportion z-test, (my favorite) likelihood ratio test of logistic regressions with the group variable as a predictor in the full model (intercept only in the reduced model)...pick one that makes sense to you where you can explain the theory to your boss. The proportion z-test is probably the easiest and the one your boss has seen.